# C# - Read a nvarchar (dd/MM/yyyy) into a dateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm attempting to read a `nvarchar` field into a dateTimePicker but I'm not sure how to convert the string into the dateTimePicker format.

I input the date into the database via the same dateTimePicker and use:

```
string dateTime = (dateTime_date.Value.Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This is the bit I'm unsure of:

```
dateTimePicker = reader["Date"].ToString();
```

Thanks, appreciate any help.

Comment: Okay so, I was being an idiot and didn't realise it would be as simple as dateTime_date.Text = reader["Date"].ToString();

Comment: Storing dates as a string in a dbase is one of the all-time Bad Ideas.  Use the native column type support for dates so your dbase data doesn't turn to into junk when you use it in another locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse(reader["Date"].ToString());
```

Comment: or to be more exact: DateTime.ParseExact(reader["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null)